# Manual boot Ubuntu 20.04 with GRUB 2.04 cannot find kernel

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I recently repartitioned my drives and immediately after that I get sent to GRUB. I look up how to manually boot using GRUB, and I see a few tutorials. I try to follow these tutorials, but I get stuck at one part every time. The kernel simply is not where it should be. I try to ls into the /boot folder to locate the kernel so I can load it, however, it spits this out:

`` 56789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefg `` (One line)

I’ve tried nearly everything there is to try, but nothing seems to work.
I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Try looking in `/casper`. on a Live USB or `/boot` on an installed system.

Comment: That random data looks like file corruption. Did resize complete correctly?